# Pass Variable into String vale which is JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, boto3

I need to pass one variable as `date` variable  in place of Sting value
I need to pass date in place of `2020-12-31`

My String Values Looks like

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date =(datetime.now() - timedelta(2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

TableMappings="""{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-action": "include",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "SCHEMA",
                "table-name": "AUDIT_TABLE"
            },
            "rule-name": "1",
            "filters": [
                {
                    "filter-type": "source",
                    "column-name": "UTC_DATE_TIME",
                    "filter-conditions": [
                        {
                            "filter-operator": "gte",
                            "value": "2020-12-31"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}"""
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's the question? What is not working or not clear?

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha so i want to make date part variable in place of hardcoded date i want to get latest date and create mapping i tired to pus escape and value in {} but did not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to operate with string representation of JSON and trying to template it, you can work with built-in `dict` data type.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date =(datetime.now() - timedelta(2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

dict_mapping = {
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-action": "include",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "SCHEMA",
                "table-name": "AUDIT_TABLE"
            },
            "rule-name": "1",
            "filters": [
                {
                    "filter-type": "source",
                    "column-name": "UTC_DATE_TIME",
                    "filter-conditions": [
                        {
                            "filter-operator": "gte",
                            "value": date
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

str_mapping = json.dumps(dict_mapping)
```

Trying to format nested multi-line strings is not convenient without using template engines like jinja2, but in the end machine on the other end of transmission wouldn't care how good it looks if it expects plain old JSON.